# What is set_value_name doing in relation to llvm global_context

Tags: ocaml, llvm, llvm-ir

I have read the llvm documentation [here](https://llvm.moe/ocaml/Llvm.html#TYPElltype) but am still confused.

So I think that when `llvm.global_context()` is called at the top of a bunch of let...in statements, this creates the "top-level container for all LLVM global data." (I don't fully understand it means though to create a top-level container for all LLVM data..)

And then later if I were to see `llvm.set_value_name n p` where p is of type llvalue

Does that mean that I have set the name of any llvalue equal to p to be n, within the context I've declared?

My whole understanding of llvm is weak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is the object that owns and manages modules, types and constants. `i32 32` equals `i32 32` within a context, but not across contexts, because both the type and the constant are defined within a context. It's possible to have two contexts in RAM at the same time, with independent sets of types, and in fact that'll happen quite often within some JIT systems.

A rough overview: Instructions live in basic blocks, each of which ends with a terminator instruction (a jump, return, etc). Basic blocks live in functions. Functions and global variables live in modules. Modules, types and constants live in contexts.

There are many complicating details. Where names live is one of them — conceptually names are unique to some parent of the named value, but the storage of names is implemented in the context, even when that's not architecturally required. IMO names being implemented there is a detail that LLVM users should disregard.